# Re-arrange columns in agenda clockreport?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-table

My Agenda clock-report is kinda wide and columns are all over the place.

My agenda clock report plist is as following:

```
 '(org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist
   (quote
    (:tcolumns 2 :level\  t :link t :maxlevel 5 :narrow 60 :formatter my-org-clocktable-notodo :properties
           ("Effort" "CLOCKSUM" "CLOCKSUM_T"))))
```

The Effort/clock columns are placed before headings:

```
| File      | Effort | CLOCKSUM | CLOCKSUM_T | ITEM | Headline  ..| Time |
```

Is it possible to put the effort/clock columns at the end, after the heading instead like so:

```
| File      | ITEM | Headline  ..| Time | Effort | CLOCKSUM | CLOCKSUM_T |
```

Answer (score 1):

A roundabout way of doing this is to simulate a clock report with column view:

```
#+BEGIN: columnview :id local :format "%70ITEM(Task) %Effort{:} %CLOCKSUM{:} %CLOCKSUM_T{:}"

#+END:
```

It avoids problems that clock reports have such as indentation and TODO keywords in headlines, but you don't get the fancy time break out or headline linking, if you are using those features.

Column view and clock reports seem to be equally lacking when it comes to sorting.

You might be able to use something like [org-collector](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-collector.html) to build something custom. [The code](http://orgmode.org/worg/code/elisp/org-collector.el) is quite short.

Comment: I read up on http://orgmode.org/manual/Capturing-column-view.html and got it to work. But the problem with this is that I can't do things like showing stats for a previous week (e.g :tstart "<-1w>" :tend "<-1d>"), but I use that extensivley for my weekly reports. I also can't seem to find a way to get it to work for more than 1 file at at time? I could work with a single file, but the date restriction is a killer. Thoughts?